# iTune Connect analytics - The URL is invalid

Tags: app-store-connect, itunesconnect-analytics

Last several days when trying to enter iTunes connect analytics it says error message:

> The URL is invalid.

I'am using chrome of version 66.0.3359.139. same happened using safari of version 11.1

Have any ideas about the error message?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before and it usually goes away if you refresh the page but this time around it seems to be a problem at Apple that's been going on since the end of April:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/101755

There are a couple of tips in that thread which are helpful, such as clicking OK then pressing esc to prevent the redirect away from the page which allows you to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is highly being discussed in Apple forums.developer.apple.com/

And the solution that works is:

You can work around it in Google Chrome by inspecting the webpage and deleting the modal window from the DOM Tree. This allows you to interact with the page again, reading stats or clicking towards an other page.

clicking OK then pressing esc as John mentioned works as well!